# Spring Shell - How To Disable All or Some Of The Built-In Commands

Tags: spring-shell

Using Spring Shell 3.0 I would like to disable some of the built-in commands, e.g. `stacktrace`, `script`.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `StandardCommandsAutoConfiguration` there are properties which can be set to disable commands. In `spring-shell-autoconfigure.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        SpringShellAutoConfiguration.class,
        JLineShellAutoConfiguration.class,
        StandardAPIAutoConfiguration.class,
        StandardCommandsAutoConfiguration.class,
        LineReaderAutoConfiguration.class,
        ShellRunnerAutoConfiguration.class,
        CompleterAutoConfiguration.class,
        ParameterResolverAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
```

An annotation on the spring configuration class.